# Popup on gridview cell hover

Tags: asp.net, gridview, popup, hover

I'm creating a gridview dynamically based on number of users selected but want to add detail when a specific cell of the gridview is hovered over/clicked. For instance if the logons of User1 was hovered over/clicked it would create a popup or another window with the details of logon times pulled from the database. TIA

[image]

Comment: you should pop up a div. that div should have a table.

Comment: You will probably need to store your unique id for each row (possibly in a hidden field) which you can use to retrieve data based on that **id**. And for the pop-up you can find lots of **J-Query** pop up windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are plenty of jQuery plug-ins that will do want you want client-side like [QTip](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/) or jQuery UI's [dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/). Where you can combine them with an Ajax call to pull whatever data you want.

**EDIT:** For information to send back client-side, you could use a hidden input to hold the information you need:

```
<td class="userId">
    <input type="hidden" class="userId" value="<%# Eval("userId") %>">
</td>
```

Then access it with jQuery (sample):

```
$("td.userId").click(function() {
    var userId = $(this).find(".userId").val();
    // use userId for ajax call.
});
```

**EDIT 2:** If you're dynamically generating the grid server-side, you can add an [HtmlInputHidden](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlinputhidden%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) to the grid cell wherever you're creating your cells:

```
var hidden = new HtmlInputHidden();
hidden.Attributes.Add("class", "userId");
hidden.Value = something.userId.ToString();
```

Comment: How do I get the row, column and/or cell data from the gridview?

Comment: Updated answer to give a general example.

Comment: That should work perfect except I'm building the gridview dynamically so I'm not sure how I can add that to the server-side code when adding each row? Or perhaps there is another way?

Comment: I've updated my answer to give an example of creating a hidden input control to add to your grid cell.